# Distributed Transaction In C# for Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, distributed-transactions

I have a C# application. I would like to run a transaction which insert and update multiple database on different location. I notice is to support via the .net connector provided by mysql. Any solution for this? What I am doing currently is that open 2 transaction then I commit one then I commit another after that which is risky as sometimes somethings fail to be updated.

Comment: you could try threads although it's hard to make out a meaning to what you're asking, can you be a little more specific to what you need help with?

Comment: I dont know if mysql supports DTC (distributed transaction coordinator) service. Then you can use TransactionScope

Comment: I would suggest looking at what the mysql provided provider supports and has built in first, then use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html.

Comment: Dear Kress,I have looked into this link before the problem is I do not know whether this supported on .net and also how to do it on .net? The .net connector give by mysql just support single transaction not multiple that is the problem here I have read the documentation before this too.